# Stop Vivaldi from reloading already opened tabs

Tags: vivaldi

With Vivaldi, if I click a tab in order to change my currently present web-app, the contained page gets reloaded. This happens for downright apps nearly everytime. For things like dictionaries (linguee etc.), it doesn't happen that often.

I'll describe an example scenario:

- Open up JIRA tab (downright web-app)
- Open up Linguee tab ("static" web-page)
- Open up Google tab
- Click on JIRA -> it reloads
- Click on Linguee -> doesn't reload
- Click on Google
- Wait one minute
- Click on JIRA -> it reloads
- Click on Linguee -> it reloads

This behaviour appears to be a little bit random. Sometimes tabs get reloaded and sometimes not. However, there is one constant thing: If I wait a time (at least one minute), without exception every tab gets reloaded.

Why does that happen and how do I disable this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this option:

```
vivaldi://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding
```

Comment: Tabs being reloaded nearly every time they focus (after being inactive for like 30-60min) has just started for me with Vivaldi 3.5 on Linux - but the automatic tab discarding flag does not exist anymore, and no other settings for this seem to exist. Has this been renamed or moved? I never had this problem before.

Comment: I do not have that flag here.

Answer (score 0):

This just started happening to me, not sure what's changed.

I've found out there are 2 ways to stop this from happening:

1. Navigate to **vivaldi://discards** and manually switch off the tabs you want to stop from refreshing in the "Auto Discardable" column

[image]

Note: this is temporary until next browser restart

2. Use [Disable automatic tab discarding Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-automatic-tab-dis/dnhngfnfolbmhgealdpolmhimnoliiok/related). This would stop ALL tabs from auto discarding.